# Ruby code to extract host from URL string

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a method to reliably extract the host name from a URL string in Ruby.

e.g. 
http://www.mglenn.com/directory = www.mglenn.com
OR
http://www.mglenn.com?param=x = www.mglenn.com

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
require 'uri'

myUri = URI.parse( 'http://www.mglenn.com/directory' )
print myUri.host
# =>  www.mglenn.com
```

Comment: Worth noting - this will fail if the URL is something like example.com (no protocol)

Comment: To allow no protocol you can do this: myUri = uri.start_with?('http') ? URI(uri) : URI("http://#{uri}"). Then call myUri.host for the host. Note that this is pretty naiv

Answer (score 28):

```
URI("http://www.mglenn.com/directory").host
```

Comment: Easiest, cleanest solution.