# What's the best way to parse URLs to extract the domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby code to extract host from URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278622/ruby-code-to-extract-host-from-url-string)

I found this module called [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html) which can parse the url. (I'm pretty new to ruby. Is 'module' synonymous with 'library' in this case?) You can then extract the host name.

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www.ruby-lang.org/")
...
p uri.host
# => "www.ruby-lang.org"
```

From this, I suppose you could remove 'www.' and keep other subdomains using regular expressions.

Does anyone have a more straight-forward alternative or does this approach seem right?

Comment: Surely ruby must have some kind of `split()` functionality. So why don't you just split the string on `www.` and keep the part after?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Just remove 'www' from the `uri.host`?

Comment: A library is generally a self-contained code resource which can include one, more or fewer modules or classes. `URI` is a module which comes in the Ruby core library, which means it's available in any ruby code you run. For all other code you have to explicitly load it into your app

Comment: Using split('www.') would work, except that it would give me an array if the host was www.example.com and a string if it was example.com so I'd have to use a conditional. Looks like I'm gonna have to do that anyway. I just figured there was a more efficient way.

Comment: Of course there is sub() method that would remove 'www.' if it found it... Answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [domainatrix](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix) gem to get what you want: `url.domain + url.public_suffix`, but you can just do some string manipulation like `uri[4..-1]`.

Comment: This gem's pretty good. I guess I could then display the subdomains that `!= 'www'`.

Answer (score 11):

So while posting my own answer, I'm not saying that gems like domainatrix or public_suffix_server aren't good elegant solutions (although the latter bugged on me immediately which caused me to go this route).

People suggesting using split() made me realize that I could just sub out 'www.' if it existed and otherwise leave domains as they are without installing gems and using 1 simple line of code:

```
url = request.original_url
domain = URI.parse(url).host.sub(/\Awww\./, '')
```

This works with subdomains and multi-part suffixes (eg. co.uk). Anybody see anything wrong with this?

EDIT: Thanks sorens for pointing out the weak regex I was originally using. This expression is certainly better.

Comment: you should tighten up your regular expression. `www.` is going to match on any string that is `www` and any other character. the period is a special regex character that means any single character. so if you were test against the site http://www2009.org/, you would end up removing "www2" and left with 009.org. at the very least, try `\Awww\.` the "\A" will force the check to only consider it at the beginning of the string and the "\." will escape the period to mean you are only looking for the period character. If you have trouble with regex, http://www.rubular.com/ is a good resource to help.