# Difference between `URI` and `URI.parse`

Tags: ruby, url, uri

What is the difference between `URI` and `URI.parse`? Here is what I get:

```
require 'uri'
x = "http://google.com"
y = URI(x)       # => #<URI::HTTP http://google.com>
z = URI.parse(x) # => #<URI::HTTP http://google.com>
y == z # => true
```

I see in the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html) that a new instance of `URI` creates a new `URI::Generic` instance from generic components without check, and that it has a default parser in the args.

The general recommendation seems to be `URI.parse`, and I am wondering why. I am wondering if there are any gotchas for using `URI` and not using `URI.parse`. Appreciate any insight.

Related: [How to Parse a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243810/3100284), [Parse URL to Get Main Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674363/3100284), [Extract Host from URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/278673/3100284).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, `URI(x)` and `URI.parse(x)` are the same.

`URI` is a method defined on `Kernel`, which basically calls `URI.parse(x)`.

We can confirm this by looking at [the source code of the `URI()` method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ca6b174078fa15f33655be704d9409fdbc4f9929/lib/uri/common.rb#L709):

```
def URI(uri)
  if uri.is_a?(URI::Generic)
    uri
  elsif uri = String.try_convert(uri)
    URI.parse(uri)
  else
    raise ArgumentError,
      "bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)"
  end
end
```

Later, in your code, the ruby parser figures out if you actually want to have a function called `URI` or the module `URI` depending on the syntax you use.